# Can someone tell me what this hover effect is?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I was looking at this page (http://montreal.ubisoft.com/en/ubisoft-our-news) and I've also noticed on other pages I've visited this hover effect when you hover over certain buttons. I was wondering how this was done, css3 or JqueryUI? If possible can someone link me to a tut or the plugin(if Jquery) Thank you ;)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Which buttons are you referring to? You can look in the source of the page to see what they are using, of course.

Comment: When you hover over the news, twitter, facebook, etc

Comment: @user2016307 Just be aware, that if at some point you want to implement the hover effect in your website, this does not work on mobile phones, so don't forget to have a fall back in this case... (I know it's a little out of topics, but all those hovers makes me sick when browsing with my phone...)

Comment: Why do you care, just move on. Thank you for being very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="welcome to stackoverflow"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#myButton
{
    background-color:blue;
}
#myButton:hover
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Choose your [colors](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)

**Exact Effects**

**HTML**

```
 <div id="parentDiv">
        <a id="myButton" href="">Welcome to StackOverflow</a>
        <div id="transparentDiv"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parentDiv
{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#myButton
{
    display:block;
    height:70px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
}
#transparentDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#parentDiv").mouseenter(function(e){
    $("#transparentDiv").slideUp(500);
});
$("#parentDiv").mouseleave(function(e){
    $("#transparentDiv").slideDown(500);
});
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/AzmUp/

Comment: Very nice but how do I achieve the effects?